# FFMPEG Extra just codec information

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am planning on using FFMPeg with Java, to detect a specific codec and convert this to another. Using the FFMpeg line -

```
    ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_streams "input.avi"
```

I can print off all of the stream information of the video, but this includes video information, audio information, all metadata, all tags and other information which I just don't need.

Question: Is it possible to launch an FFMpeg command which only returns the video codec, so I don't have to wave through unnecessary information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about simply [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep)ing the string?

`ffprobe -v quiet -show_streams -select_streams v input.avi  | grep "codec_name"`

You can also `cut` the output and read the plain string:

`ffprobe -v quiet -show_streams -select_streams v output.mpg  | grep "codec_name" | cut -d= -f 2`

if you're on windows:

`ffprobe -v quiet -show_streams -select_streams v input.avi  | find /i "codec_name"`

Comment: You can add the `-select_streams` option in `ffprobe` to output only the video information. `-select_streams v` will output all video streams (in case there is more than one), and `-select_streams v:0` will output only the first video stream. See documentation on [stream specifiers](http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html#Stream-specifiers-1) and [`-select_streams`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html#Main-options) for more info.

Comment: @EladG - I can't grep as I am on windows unfortunately, otherwise that would have been perfect.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard - I have tried your tips also, but without any positive results. I have the line 
    _ffprobe -select_streams v "input.wmv"_ and it prints information, but nothing about the codec that I can see.

Comment: @EladG - I'll give it a quick run.

Comment: Works like a dream! Thanks Pal. I owe you a beer. @EladG

Comment: I ended up using Jackson Java for JSON objects. Just because PC's are windows, and Server arn't. So - a Java solution was required.

My solution is: 

_'BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(in);
   
   return rootNode.findValue("codec_name").getTextValue();'_

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit too late, here is a single command to show the codec name of the first video stream:

```
ffprobe -v quiet \
  -select_streams v:0 \
  -show_entries 'stream=codec_name' \
  -print_format 'default=nk=1:nw=1' INFILE
```

Or, a shorter alternative:

```
ffprobe -v quiet \
    -select_streams v:0 \
    -show_entries 'stream=codec_name' \
    -of 'csv=p=0' INFILE
```

See also the documentation at http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html

Answer (score 0):

This works beautifully on Windows/VBScript (yes the multiple rabbits ears are required:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

TheCommand = "cmd /c [PathTo]\ffprobe.exe -v quiet -show_streams -select_streams v ""    [PathTo]\FileName.avi"" | find /i ""codec_name""" 

Set objExec = objShell.Exec(TheCommand)

Do
    retCodec = retCodec & objExec.StdOut.ReadLine()
Loop While Not objExec.Stdout.atEndOfStream

WScript.Echo(retCodec)
```

Comment: I'm currently working on a recursive version that will run through a folder structure and export results to a CSV file. Happy to share if anyone interested... in return, perhaps someone can answer this: I have to convert AVI's to have XVID Codec, is there an easy way to do this ?